# MySQLi Connections in include files and functions

Tags: php, function, mysqli, include, global

I've started converting all my old websites from MySQL to MySQLi. The issue I'm having is that some functions I use have stopped working and also files that are "included" or use a config file (with the connection) are not successfully connecting. I found an answer on here on how to make a connection.

**EXAMPLE**

**config.php**

```
class DBi {
    public static $db;
}

DBi::$db = new mysqli('host', 'uname', 'pword', 'database');

if ($db->connect_error) {
  die('Connect Error (' . $db->connect_errno . ') '
  .$db->connect_error);
}
```

**search-autocomplete-business-names.php**

```
<?

require_once ('config.php');

if (!isset($_REQUEST['term'])) {

  exit;

} else {

  $rs = DBi::$db->query('SELECT...');

  $data = array();

  if ($rs && $rs->num_rows) {

    while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()) {

      $busname = htmlspecialchars_decode($row['BName'], ENT_QUOTES);
      $label = $busname;
      $data[] = array(
        'label' =>  $label,
        'value' => $row['BName']

      );

   }

}

echo json_encode($data);
flush();

}

?>
```

**Javascript that uses the above include**

```
<script>
<!-- business name autocomplete -->
$(function() {
  $(".src-bn").autocomplete({
    type: "POST",
    source: "lib/search-autocomplete-business-names.php",
    minLength: 1,
    focus: function(e, t) {
      return $(".src-bn").val(t.item.label), $(".src-spc").val(t.item.value), !1
    },
    select: function(e, t) {
      return $(".src-bn").val(t.item.label), $(".src-spc").val(t.item.value), !1
      }
    }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(e, t) {
      return $("<li>").append("<a>" + t.label + "</a>").appendTo(e)
    }
  });
</script>
```

What I want is to be able to create a connection that I can run in any file, whether it's a main page, within a function or an included file. Any ideas please? Thank you in advance.

G

Comment: What errors are you actually getting? Do you have xdebug setup with an ide? You could easily step through the connection process.

Comment: @Zarathuztra I'm getting in the error log: [01-Mar-2015 11:08:53 Europe/London] PHP Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user 'compare'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/compare/public_html/lib/search-autocomplete-business-names.php on line 11 [01-Mar-2015 11:08:53 Europe/London] PHP Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/compare/public_html/lib/search-autocomplete-business-names.php on line 11. Which is this line of code "$rs = DBi::$db->query('SELECT...');" Cheers G

Comment: The credentials for the database are wrong. See the "using password: NO". Do you have a password setup for that user?